# Using LazyListScope Nested Composables

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a composable that needs to iterate over and render a `Map<String, List<String>>`. They key is a "header" and the list sub-items.

I would like to write my code as follows:

```
@Composable
fun renderFullMap(groupedItems: Map<String, List<String>>) {
  LazyColumn {
    groupedItems.forEach { (header, things) ->
      renderSection(header, things)
    }
  }
}

@Composable
fun renderSection(header: String, things: List<String>) {
  stickyHeader { Text(header) }
  items(things) { thing -> Text(thing) }
}
```

(In practice, the actual data and `renderSection` are both more complicated, but they boil down to this basic idea.)

This doesn't work. It tells me:

> @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function

If I use `items` to iterate over my map keys, I get a different error:

```
@Composable
fun renderFullMap(groupedItems: Map<String, List<String>>) {
  LazyColumn {
    items(groupedItems.keys.toList()) { header ->
      renderSection(header, groupedItems[header])
    }
  }
}
```

With this version, `stickyHeader` and `items` are undefined inside of `renderSection`.

One last thing I tried - prefixing `renderSection` with `LazyListScope.`:

```
@Composable
fun LazyListScope.renderSection(header: String, things: List<String>) {
  stickyHeader { Text(header) }
  items(things) { thing -> Text(thing) }
}
```

This was just a stab in the dark. If I call that in a `forEach` it tells me it gives me the first error about Composables only callable from other Composables. If I call it from within `items()`:

> 'fun LazyListScope.renderSection(header: String, things: List): Unit' can't be called in this context by implicit receiver. Use the explicit one if necessary

I won't pretend to know what that means.

How do I make this work? I suspect I somehow need to extends LazyListScope down into `renderSection` but am unclear as to how.

Edit: I sort of made it work, but my list items are multiplying as I scroll around. This code compiles:

```
@Composable
fun renderFullMap(groupedItems: Map<String, List<String>>) {
  LazyColumn {
    val scope = this
    items(groupedItems.keys.toList()) { header ->
      scope.renderSection(header, groupedItems[header])
    }
  }
}

@Composable
fun LazyListScope.renderSection(header: String, things: List<String>) {
  stickyHeader { Text(header) }
  items(things) { thing -> Text(thing) }
}
```

I don't know why the contents of the list is out of whack, however.

Comment: I am guessing that the scrolling wonkiness has something to do with not defining a proper `key` function, but adding one to both invocations of `items` does not seem to help.

Comment: The implicit context error just means that you can only call the `LazyListScope` extensions from a `LazyListScope `itself. I mean that is the implication, right? Like RowScope Extensions can only be used within a Row? So when you use that in the `items` block, it throws that error. Since that is not the expected context for the extension..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your first approach is close to the correct one, you need to remove `@Composable` from `renderSection` and add `LazyListScope` context:

```
@Composable
fun renderFullMap(groupedItems: Map<String, List<String>>) {
  LazyColumn {
    groupedItems.forEach { (header, things) ->
      renderSection(header, things)
    }
  }
}

fun LazyListScope.renderSection(header: String, things: List<String>) {
  stickyHeader { Text(header) }
  items(things) { thing -> Text(thing) }
}
```